# Cant access other files in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, require

**NOTE:** There are the same questions on Stack Overflow, but this is NOT a duplicate. Please read carefully.

I'm just getting started with Socket.io on Node, and in my HTML file, I couldn't acess other files, such as pictures. I've seen answers for this on Stack Overflow, but none of them helped me.

I am serving an HTML file to the client, where my HTML file is located in /client/display/index.html

Here's what I tried: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`
And variations of that (including folder names instead of public), and I required path in the top of my file, and I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: express is not defined
    at /home/runner/Buzzer/index.js:6:9
    at Script.runInContext (vm.js:130:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/run_dir/interp.js:209:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

I already installed everythin I needed. Here's what I added that gave it an error:

```js
const path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));
```

And here are some other top stuff in my node file:

```js
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

Would really appreciate this if someone could help me.

#### [EDIT]

Seems like if I put anything inside a folder, the js file can't find it.

Comment: you need to require express  EDIT: as express or you have to use the name you required it as with .static

Comment: But I literally wrote `var app = require('express')();` on the top line, as you can see.

Comment: you need to use the same name with express.static, so "app.static" or requiring express

Comment: Can you answer the question or be more clear? I'm just beginning node.

Comment: Also, why is there a parentheses in the end if the require? What's the difference between the parentheses and no parentheses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I realized that `('express')()` is different from `('express')`.

I added:

```js
var express = require('express');

const path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));
```

And that solved my problem.

Comment: just like my answer, congrats

Comment: So is `var app = require('express')()` a shortcut for `var express = require('express');app = express();`?

Answer (score 4):

As you can see in your error: 'ReferenceError: express is not defined', you need to require express to invoke the static method, try this:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

const path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/'));
```