# Combining client-side jQuery and server - side Express

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, forms, express

I'm learning Express / Node. I'm trying to build a simple HTML `form` which I validate client - side (e.g, with jQuery / AJAX) but I also serve from the server - side (with Express.js). To be clear, the app is now simple enough that I *could* do everything client - side, but I want to build server - side behavior to learn the entire pipeline.

Here's the form. Note the `button` of type `button` with name `change-color`; this is a `button` that I use for debugging purposes, explained later. I am also including `jquery` v.3.6.0 and my own `client.js` file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>A MWE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>A simple form.</h1>
    <form action="/" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="num1" placeholder = "First Number" value=""> <br>
      <input type="text" name="num2" placeholder = "Second Number" value=""> <br>
      <button type="submit" name="submit">Calculate</button>
      <button type="button" name="change-color">Change color</button>
    </form>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="client.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the form, the user is supposed to give me two numbers, which the server will then sum and return. Server code is inside a file called `server.js`, outlined below:

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server spun on port 3000.");
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log("Serving a GET request at root route.");
  res.sendFile(absoluteDirPath() + "index.html");
});

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log("Serving a POST request at root route.");
  const num1 = Number(req.body.num1);
  const num2 = Number(req.body.num2);
  res.send("<h3>Result: " + (num1 + num2) + "</h3>");
});

function absoluteDirPath() {
  const path = require('path');
  return __dirname + path.sep;
}
```

When we first access the root endpoint (GET call), the server uses `res.sendFile()` to send the above HTML file to the user. When the user inputs two numbers on the `form` and clicks on the `button` of type `submit` inside the `form`, the `app.post()` of `server.js` method calculates and `send()`s the requested sum.

Clearly I need to do some validation before I apply the summation; what if I don't get a number? Based on the answers to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67443551/send-error-message-and-re-direct-in-express-js), to avoid complex and sudden redirections, I seem to have to do this on the client side, e.g, in a separate `.js` file. In the same post, I have been advised to author something like the following function and assign it to an event listener:

```js
function submitFormWithoutReloading() {
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/",
      data: {
         num1: $('#idOfYourFirstInput').val(),
         num2: $('#idOfYourSecondInput').val()
      },
      success: function(res) {
         alert(res); // This is what the server returns
      }
   });
}
```

However, I seem to have stumbled upon a bigger issue here. I am having some trouble running all my jQuery when I serve the user with the HTML file from the `app.get()` method! It seems as if every time I access `http://localhost:3000/`, the HTML file is sent to me, but the linked `client.js` file is not read (and I am guessing that the same thing holds for jQuery).

To ensure that this is what my problem is, I temporarily forgot about the validation routine, made the `change-color` HTML `button` mentioned above and added some dummy code to `client.js`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert("Hi!");
});

$('button[name="change-color"]').click(function() {
  $("body").toggleClass("colored-background");
});
```

So the `change-color` button is used just to toggle the `body` element to have `yellow` as its background as per this CSS rule:

```css
.colored-background {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

If I open `index.html` from my filesystem, it all works just fine; `jQuery` and my `client.js` file are loaded, the `alert()` comes just fine, and the button works as intended. But when I access `localhost:3000` and the `GET` endpoint serves the client with the HTML file, it's as if the DOM scanning does not read `client.js` and I can't do any client - side stuff, including my much desired validation!

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong? I know I could do *everything* on the client side here, but I want to learn how to split the concerns on client side and server side. Server side might want to access a DB, the client can't do everything.

// Edit: If it helps, the Chrome console says some interesting things when I load `localhost:3000`:

[image: Output of Chrome console when I access localhost:3000.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You didn't do anything wrong*. This is just a common problem that everyone using node.js (including me! [Cant access other files in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66718635/cant-access-other-files-in-node-js)).

You have to tell express which files can be viewed by the client. Let's create a folder called `public`. Inside your folder, put you `.js` and `.css` files, as well as other pictures or other assets you want accessible by the client side.

This folder, public, on your website will be replaced with your domain. Consider these files/folders:

```
index.js (server)
/ views
   - index.html
/ public
   - style.css
   - client.js
   - jquery.min.js
```

The client can only access the files inside `public`, like this: `http://localhost:3000/style.css`, or `http://localhost:3000/client.js`, or `http://localhost:3000/jquery.min.js`. However, we will not be able to access the other files (not in the public folder), unless the server explicitly gets it:

```js
app.get('/index.html', function(req, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/views/index.html'));
});
```

## Solution:

```js
// ...
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
// You routes here
```

This way, the client will be able to access all the files under the `public` directory. Your problem should be solved.

**Keep in mind:** The server can still access all the files. This only restricts the client side.

Comment: Ha, yes, I was actually served the same solution by a friend and I was coming back to answer my own question, but better to give somebody else the points. This works A-Ok, now I have client - side and server - side separation of concerns in a single language, just as advertised. Thank you!

Comment: Yay! I'm glad you had your problem fixed. I'd be happy to help you with other questions (that I can answer)